# removing item from result query in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I can't remove an item from query result array in php + codeigniter.

This is my code

```
if($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
    $rows = $query->result();
        foreach ($rows as $key => $row)
        {
            $i = 0;
            $fornecedor = $row->fornecedor;
            $marca = $row->marca;
            $modelo = $row->modelo;
            $versao = $row->versao;
            $preco = $row->preco;

                foreach ($rows as $row2)
                {
                    $fornecedor2 = $row2->fornecedor;
                    $marca2 = $row2->marca;
                    $modelo2 = $row2->modelo;
                    $versao2 = $row2->versao;
                    $preco2 = $row2->preco;

                    if(($fornecedor == $fornecedor2) && ($marca == $marca2) && ($modelo == $modelo2) && ($versao == $versao2) && ($preco == $preco2))
                    {
                        $i++;
                    }
                }

            if($i > 3)
            {
                unset($row[$key]);
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

I already checked some examples here in stackoverflow but i cant make this work.
I can't see the problem ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so `$row` is a `$rows[$key]`, maybe i don't understand something, but it's seems to me you have to write `unset($rows[$key]);`